# Outlook blocks all Amazon S3 public images URL

Tags: amazon-s3, outlook, spam

When I add the image URL from the Amazon S3 bucket in the html email and send it out from our email server, the html email will be marked as junk email because the Amazon S3 image URL. This is the example what I added in the html email:

```
<img style="height: 60px; width: 200px;" alt="" src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/tickitin/event-img/20168/d696cef742144426844e0647e89701ac.jpg" />
I tried to update the src in the <img>
```

to other URLs like this one: https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

The html email won't be blocked and was sent into inbox. I tried other public images online of Amazon S3 bucket and found all these images with the prefix URL https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com will be blocked. Please help look into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

External images are blocked by default in Outlook.

You need to attach images to the email and set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the email (the DASL name is  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"). In message bodies you can refer to such images by using their Content ID names (assigned to the property earlier).

See [Embed Images in New Messages using a Macro](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/embed-images-messages-macro/) for more information.